# List of Spring Boot provided beans?

Tags: spring-boot

Is there a list of beans provided by Spring Boot and its different modules?  For example, I only recently discovered that Spring Boot already provides a configurable Jackson ObjectMapper bean.  I would have never known that if not for reading up on an unrelated issue I was dealing with.  Now I'm working with Spring JMS and am afraid that I am reinventing the wheel because Spring Boot may already have what I need and I just don't know about it.  How are these beans discovered?  They don't seem to be cataloged in any Spring documentation.

Comment: Are you looking for actuator? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready

Comment: @soon I understand this answer.  I was hoping that there could be something I could reference as I was developing.

Comment: By reference you mean use from the code? You can look at github to see how beans endpoint is implemented: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/beans/BeansEndpoint.java

Comment: @soon By reference, I mean going to a web page and seeing an actual list of beans that are provided by and Spring Boot and Spring projects that I can autowire.

Comment: Actuator provides web api for you. It is simple json, though you can also look at all beans using Endpoints > Beans window in IDEA

Comment: @soon Ok, I'll give that a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend starting with the reference documentation. While it doesn't list every bean that may be auto-configured, it does have documentation describing each feature area that may be auto-configured. For example, there are sections on [Jackson's `ObjectMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) and on [JMS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jms).

Each starter that Spring Boot offers is also a good indication of what it can auto-configure. Each first-party starter is [listed](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter) in the documentation.

Comment: This made me realize that I'm probably looking in the wrong place for some of these beans.  I should also be looking at the normal Spring docs, such as for my JMS questions.